# Is there a way to join two columns and have a single row as key value pair of the new column rather than the whole column?

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc and pandas to fetch data from a database in different machine. I have written the SQL for getting the end dataframe of 45 columns, which are then going to be send to people above for verification. But as such the dataframe looks bad and cluttered.

Some of the columns such as

```
 0, 'Windows Vista'
'error_info_id', 'error_info_description',
0, 'no error'
 'user_status_id', 'user_status_details',
1,'off'
 'volume_letter','volume_id','volume_cost','volume_date','volume_end_date'
'C','asd12edsdasd',100,'2019-09-09 16:45:46.007','2022-09-09 16:45:46.007
```

can be merged in one like

```
operating system
{'Id': 0, 'name': 'Windows Vista'}
'error_info'
{'Id': 0, 'name':'no error'}
 'user_status'
{'Id': 1, 'name':'off'}
 'volume_letter','volume_id','volume_cost','volume_date','volume_end_date'
{'Id': 'asd12edsdasd', 'letter':'C','cost':100,'startdate':'2019-09-09 16:45:46.007','enddate':'2022-09-09 16:45:46.007'}
```

I've tried this 
`final_result = {**mvalue, **vvalue}`
 by taking these two columns as per one of the SO answer's. But it concatenated both columns into one. it made something like 
`error = {'0':'no error', '1':'error', '2': 'under obeservation'}`

can't show much of the code, but for trial purposes, it can be tried like

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'id': [1, 2,3], 'system_name': ['abc','qrs','mln'], 'operating_system_id': [0,0,1], 'operating_system_name': ['Windows Vista', 'Windows Vista', Win&7'], 'error_info_id': [0,1,1], 'error_info_description':['no error', 'error', 'error'],'volume_letter': ['C','C','C'],'volume_id': ['12edsdasd', 'asd12edsd', 'asd12edasd'],'volume_cost':[100,100,100],'volume_date':['2019-09-09 16:45:46.007', '2019-09-09 16:45:46.007', '2019-09-09 16:45:46.007'],'volume_end_date':['2022-09-09 16:45:46.007','2022-09-09 16:45:46.007','2022-09-09 16:45:46.007']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Can these be merged in one like dictionary per row?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question, but in case you want to transform each row to a dictionary, you can use the [pandas.DataFrame.to_dict('records')](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method.

```py
    In[132]: df.to_dict('records') 
    Out[132]: [{'id': 1, 'system_name': 'abc', 'operating_system_id': 0, 'operating_system_name': 'Windows Vista', 'error_info_id': 0, 'error_info_description': 'no error', 'volume_letter': 'C', 'volume_id': '12edsdasd', 'volume_cost': 100, 'volume_date': '2019-09-09 16:45:46.007', 'volume_end_date': '2022-09-09 16:45:46.007'},
     {'id': 2, 'system_name': 'qrs', 'operating_system_id': 0, 'operating_system_name': 'Windows Vista', 'error_info_id': 1, 'error_info_description': 'error', 'volume_letter': 'C', 'volume_id': 'asd12edsd', 'volume_cost': 100, 'volume_date': '2019-09-09 16:45:46.007', 'volume_end_date': '2022-09-09 16:45:46.007'}, 
     {'id': 3, 'system_name': 'mln', 'operating_system_id': 1, 'operating_system_name': 'Win&7', 'error_info_id': 1, 'error_info_description': 'error', 'volume_letter': 'C', 'volume_id': 'asd12edasd', 'volume_cost': 100, 'volume_date': '2019-09-09 16:45:46.007', 'volume_end_date': '2022-09-09 16:45:46.007'}]
```

Comment: Hey weiqiman, I want the two columns to become a single column and the values the columns become a dictionary. So if colA has int value and colB has str value. colC the merge of these two columns will be a dictionary with key as int and value as str.

But I want this to happen for individual row, my method converted the whole column into dictionary. I hope this clears up

Answer (score 0):

Had to go through the whole documentation, but inital solution is found

```
result['operating_system'] = result.apply(lambda row: {'id' : row.operating_system_id, 'name':row.operating_system_name}, axis=1)
```

Now every row will have individual row.